# apache log to find out what a php file/function did

Tags: php, apache, logging

Is there any way to log what happens when a php file/function is executed? Suppose i write a php script (create.php) to create folders/directories on the fly so will apache log this and tell me that it was (create.php) that has created the folders.. also is this kind of logging already done by apache?
Thanks.

Comment: Apache logs requests to Apache, if you want to log what PHP scripts actually do you need to log that within PHP

Comment: Generally, no. Apache will log the page hits, and any errors, but not log your programs for you. Logging this type of activity is your responsibility.

Comment: @MarkBaker would you like posting this as an answer so that i can mark it as the correct answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple answer is that Apache does not log anything that PHP gets up to.

You may wish to look into [log4php](http://logging.apache.org/log4php) to do the business.